# Qt basics regarding its structructure

Tags: qt

I have been working with Qt not too long ago, there is the concept of polymorphism I am traying to get around, but I wonder if any Qt classes can be used to work with another. In other words, can I use a Qpen class to write on a QLabel on real time, if so, how would the syntax be?

Comment: It looks like you have too shallow understanding of Qt. It will be better to start from reading its documentation or specialized books at first. For drawing on QLabel ([QPaintDevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qpaintdevice.html)) you should use [QPainter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qpainter.html) and QPen is just a descriptor of the pen.

Answer (score 0):

Example code snippet for how easy it is to program with Qt. Though you still need some more program logic you must first learn from the Qt tutorial and examples:

```
...
QLabel* label = new QLabel("test");
...
QPen pen(Qt::black);
QPainter painter(label);
painter.setPen(pen);
painter.drawPoint(10,10);
...
```